# adding java core libraries from maven central repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml, rt.jar

I am new to maven.
I was trying a simple maven project in which i want to include the core java library from maven central repository.
I found this dependency from search.maven.org

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sun</groupId>
<artifactId>rt</artifactId>
<version>1.5.0_06</version>
<name>Sun Java Runtime Environment</name>
<description>Java Runtime Environment that can be found in Sun's JRE lib folder</description>
```

But maven stores rt's pom in local repository, i am not able to access rt jar which has java core libraries.

Comment: The rt.jar is part of your Java Installation (JRE). So you don't need to define a dependency apart from that JRE is not in Central.

Comment: then why is that dependency present in the maven repo

Comment: Those artifacts are from 2006 means 8 years old...apart from that you really don't need 1.5 deps, cause it's long EoL etc. (1.6 also) Furthermore those artifacts are in central based on an error, cause it's not legal to distribute artifacts like this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following :

# Create maven project using Eclipse

# Open pom.xml and add following build tag

Refer below sample pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ays</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-solution</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Added Java8 support -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

# Right click on Project and choose Maven-> Update Project...

# Refresh your project you will see JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]

# Hope this will helps!!